# Single word to describe "homogeneous" and "isotropic" matter?

Tags: terminology

Is there a single word to describe materials which both have a homogeneous and isotropic permittivity and permeability?

There are just too many "homogeneous and isotropic materials" and "homogeneous and non-isotropic materials" in my text. And it's the worst in headlines.

Comment: How would this word help with “homogeneous and *non*-isotropic materials"? Do you understand that there are four combinations? And what headlines are you talking about? I have never seen these words in any headline.

Comment: @G.Smith I understand that there are four combinations. I'm only interested in these two though. The headlines are e.g. "General wave solutions in homogeneous and  isotropic materials". For the non-isotropic case I just write "Wave solutions in birefringent materials" and I was wondering, whether there is something similar for the isotropic case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such word in standard physics terminology.  If there were, you would encounter it all the time—in solid state physics, cosmology, and elsewhere.

The name of the group of symmetries of three-dimensional Euclidean space (generated by rotations, translations, and reflection) is the Euclidean group $E(3)$, so you could refer to a system as “$E(3)$-invariant.”  However, this would not apply to finite blocks of material (which are homogeneous and isotropic internally, but not globally as a $E(3)$-symmetric system would be).